# sql where has two conditions but one field has index, can it improve performence?

Tags: sql

I have a sql statement:

```
SELECT * FROM table 
WHERE field1 = value1 AND field2 = value2
```

If I create a index for column field1 and field2 does not have index. Can this improve the performance. IF so why ?

Comment: Index won't be of much help,if your table has many columns .Index may be of some help if your table has only two columns.But again there are many unknowns

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? Postgres? Oracle? "_SQL_" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product.

Comment: The answer is: probably. (Depends on the table data. Worst case scenario, if all rows have the same field1 value, the index will make no improvement at all.)

Comment: Thank you all for your answer. I have understood and got the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, an index can be used for part of a `where` clause as well as for the entire `where` clause.  This is because the clauses are connected by `and`.

Essentially what happens is the index on `field1` is used to fetch the rows that match `value1`.  The data pages are then loaded and the filtering continues for the rest of the conditions.

Answer (score 1):

You can think of it as that the first part of the where is filtering out the dataset to continue working on, so if a large number of rows have `field1 = value1` an index on field2 can help with performance. The only way to know if an index will help is to run `EXPLAIN` on the query and analyze the result.

To many indexes on a table will hurt insert performance, so you need to find the right balance based on your data-structure and our data

Comment: Thanks your answer, it is very helpful.